# cannot add 1 to an unsigned integer made by construct_uint

Tags: rust

I am trying to write a program that calculates the n^n! of any given positive integer in rust, I am using the uint crate to manage the very big numbers that I will be dealing with. However, I have accomplished everything I need, except, when I try to add 1 to the integer I made as 1024 bits, it does not allow this however, as it says that they are mismatched types. How can I make it so that I can do this. I am also welcome to other suggestions as to how to do this. Thank you, kind stranger for helping me.

The code of "main.rs"

```rust
use std::io;
use uint::construct_uint;

fn main() {
    construct_uint! {
        pub struct U1024(16);
    };

    let mut factorial: U1024;

    println!("What is n?");

    let mut number = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut number)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    let n = number.parse::<i32>().unwrap();

    for i in 1..n+1 {
        // This is the bit that makes it not compile
        let mut x: U1024;
        x += 1;
        factorial = factorial * x
    }

    let mut result: U1024;

    result = factorial * factorial;

    println!("n^n! is {}", result);
}
```

P.S. (My full code can be found here: https://github.com/pigeon-king-17/ntonfactorial)

Comment: Try `x += U1024::from(1u64);` or `x += U1024::one();`.